# How to get specific value from Firebase Database and save it in another place

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve a specific value (Firebase Database) from a child in my case called `handlename`.
The problem is: I don't know how to get that value stored with the `userID`:

[image: look of an User]

I want to get the handlename but I dont know how to access it as it is different from user to user and save it as a string.
I want to achieve this for saving it for a comment in another place.
Here is how one comment looks:

[image: Comment]

Instead of the `userID` (see Comment) I need the handlename stored in another place (see the first Picture).